# PHP sessions system crashes

Tags: php, linux, apache, session, redhat

I created a relatively small php/mysql based website and hosted it on a server running Red Hat 6.4, Apache/2.2.15. In order to access the site, the users are required to authenticate.

Now comes the weird problem. When I start the server, the site initially runs fine, but after about 12-24 hours, the php sessions stop working. When users try to login, their credentials a successfully retrieved from the database and the login script sets up the session variables, but when they are redirected to the home page - the session variables are lost so the home page thinks they aren't logged in and they are redirected back to the login page. The site is not heavily used, there are about 50 registered users and there are under 100 logins daily. Also, the site requires an invitation code to register, so the probability for bots to be on the site is very small.

Below are the PHP functions used to start a session, to log the users in and to check if they are authenticated (the code was inspired from http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL):

```
function SecSessionStart() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false;//https is not enforced
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}

function Login($username, $password) {
    $username=trim($username);
    if (CheckUserCredentials($username, $password))
    {
        $userId=GetUserIdByUsername($username);
        $hashedPass=hash("sha512",$password);


        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId;
        // XSS protection as we might print this value
        $username = strtolower($username);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $hashedPass.$user_browser);
        // Login successful.
        session_write_close();
        return true;
    } 
    else {        
        session_write_close();  
        return false;
    }
}

function LoginCheck() {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) 
    { 
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $hash=GetPasswordHashByUserId($user_id);
        if ($hash==null)
        {       
            session_destroy();
            session_write_close();
            return false;
        }

        $login_check = hash('sha512', $hash.$user_browser);

        if ($login_check == $login_string) {
            // Logged In
            session_write_close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            session_destroy();
            session_write_close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    return false;
}
```

In order to test my assumption that the problem was related to the sessions, I made the following php page and I've set up monitoring on it once every 5 minutes on an uptime checker:

```
<?php
require_once("include/authentication.php");
SecSessionStart();
$_SESSION['sessionCheck'] = "The cookie was successfully saved and retrieved";
session_write_close();

$_SESSION['sessionCheck']="";

SecSessionStart();
if (isset($_SESSION['sessionCheck']))
{
echo($_SESSION['sessionCheck']);
}
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
?>
```

Just as I suspected, the page returned the right answer for about 20 hours then I got an alert that the page was not displaying the success string. After I got the alert the login part on the site didn't work, either. I've tried to restart the httpd process to bring back to life the sessions, but this did not help. Only after a complete server restart things got back to normal.

I have tried searching on SO and other sites for my problem and I found some questions that were somehow related, but they did not entirely fit my situation. The main difference between my problem and other similar ones its that the site works perfectly fine in the beginning, but after some time the sessions fail all of the time. Other posters had problems where they lost sessions from time to time or the sessions did not work at all.

Any hint on the possible source of this problem would be kindly appreciated. If you need any further information from me that could help, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Where are your sessions stored? What are the values of `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path` in your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini?

Comment: save_handler=files; save_path=/var/lib/php/session

Comment: and I've checked that path, it has 6204 files, the oldest one being from January 14. Should there be so many files?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Maybe just take a look at this directory, when the problem shows up again and check how much space is left on the device and things like that. The fact that your problem disappears again after 24 hours could point to some cleanup mechanism, maybe logrotate, that frees up some space.